# Avoid restarting server every time when tiny changes on integration tests

Tags: java, spring, integration, spock

Avoid restarting the server every time when tiny changes on integration tests

I'm new to Spring and feeling a lot of pain on writing integration tests on Spring.

For example, say I'm running an integration test and change the code below.

See, there's nothing related to the server code change.

To run the new updated integration test code, I have to launch the webserver and data seeding again which might take 5 minutes long.

Hard to imaging how people manage this way for development.

I'm not sure if it is possible to launch the webserver along by `bootRun` and the integration test should try to communicate the dedicate server without bothering to reboot the servers for running tests.

Usually, which part config file will define this behavior?

I took over this project and have to figure it out my own.

## Before

```
    serverResp.then()
            .statusCode(203)
            .body("query.startDateTime", equalTo("2018-07-01T00:00:00"))
```

## After

```
    serverResp.then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("query.endDateTime", equalTo("2020-07-01T00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Would be usefull, if you post your complete spring integration test.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different way to do integration testing.
Spring has a built-in framework that runs the integration test in the same JVM as the real server.
If the application is heavy (usually relevant for monoliths) it indeed can take time to run it, the best you can do then is to "chose" which parts of the application to load that are relevant to the test. In spring there are ways to achieve this, the question is whether your application code allows such separation.

Then there is a way to write integration tests so that they indeed communicate with a remote server which is up-and-running "in advance". during the build this can be done once before a testing phase and then when the tests are done, the server should be shut down.

Usually tests like this have some ways to specify the server host/port for communications (I put aside the security, credentials, etc).
So you can check if there is some special flag/system property - read the host  / port from there.

A good thing in this approach is that you won't need to restart the server before every test.
The bad thing is that it doesn't always allow to test easily: If your test deploys some test data, this test must also remove the data at the end of test. 
Tests must be designed carefully.

A third approach is a kind of hybrid and generally not a mainstream IMO:
you can create a special setup that will run test in different JVM (externally) but once the test starts its bytecode gets uploaded to the running server (the server must have a backdoor for this) and the actual bytecode gets executed actually on the server. Again the server is up-and-running.

I wrote once a library to do this with Spock, but it was long time ago and we haven't used it after all (that project was closed).

Don't want to self-advertise or something, but you can [check it out](https://github.com/MarkBramnik/rtest) and maybe borrow technical ideas of how to do this.